# How to override bnd Require-Capability generated from DS annotation?

Tags: osgi, declarative-services, bnd

I have a bundle with an "optional" Component : It should be started if at leat one service of type X exist, and deactivated when the last service is unregistered.

This component is "optional": It doesn't matter if X is registered or not, or if my component is activated or not. It's just an helper for managing instances of X.

My component is declared like this :

```
@Component
public class MyManager {

  @Reference(cardinality=AT_LEAST_ONE)
  public void addService(X service) { .. }
}
```

However, bnd generate a `Require-Capability` for at least one service X.

How can I tell bnd that my component is optional, and all it dependencies are optionals ? I can change the implementation of my component to add lazynes "by hand", but I would rather use DS capabilities.

Comment: If you make the cardinality MULTIPLE then you get an optional dependency. We had a discussion to change even AT_LEAST_ONE to optional but surprisingly opinions differed.

Comment: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/1364 requests a way to disable generation of the osgi.service capabilities and requirements for DS components. You may want to add a comment with your interest there.